# Crash after upgrading gcc version on linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I upgrade my compiler version from GCC 7 to GCC 11.

When I try to run the process on the machine where I build the binary, I have no issue.
But when launching the process on the production machine I get a crash systemically in a std::list of boost shared ptrs

What's is going on with this machine (same linux distribution version) ?
Could you please help ?

Comment: We are missing a lot of detail! "Crash systematically" What happens? Is there any output you can share? Do you have a minimal amount of code (MCVE) this happens for? Is there compilation that works? IS this only for code including boost? What linux distro and versions are you using. Also GCC4 to GCC11 is a huge jump - expect some teething issues.

Comment: c++11 caused libstdc++ to [change the ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) of `std::list` and `std::string`

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. What can I do to fix the issue? What library I need to add to package. Thank you.

Comment: I'm wrong the old version of gcc is 7

Comment: Saad Rami, why do you think you can run a "libstdc++.so.6.0.29 application" on another OS with e.g.  `libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.24` ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen The libstdc++ ABI would be the same between such versions, though?

Comment: When you are running the app on an OS different from the build OS, then `libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.29` is required.